# Keep original and clone on successful drags

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

How can I keep the original and the clone on a successful drag?

```
$('.definition').draggable({'revert':'invalid', 'helper':'clone'});
```

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623703/clone-node-on-drag

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347295/jquery-ui-drag-and-drop-problem

Comment: Thank you... I actually saw this post but misread the solution when I tried to implement it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(this).append($(ui.draggable).clone());